# What is the mechanism by which sugars glycate proteins?

Tags: biochemistry

I was looking at why it's ok for glucose to circulate through the blood while fructose is prevented from doing so by the liver.  Fructose glycates proteins more readily than glucose.  This is the opposite of what I expected as glucose is an aldose while fructose is a ketose.  It seems reasonable to expect that the aldose would be more reactive than the ketose in many reactions.  What is the mechanism of glycation of proteins?

Comment: What is the source for the idea that fructose is more active at glycation than glucose?  I found an [in vitro paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jf051565n) that shows the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

One mechanism of glycation is the [Maillard Reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction).

The mechanism starts with nucleophilic attack of the sugar carbonyl group by a side chain amino group from the protein.

The Milliard Reaction occurs in the human body and has been implicated in various adverse health conditions.

The cornea, lens and retina are known to be damaged by this reaction.

See [The Maillard reaction in the human body. The main discoveries and factors that affect glycation](http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0369811409001928?via=sd&cc=y) Pathologie Biologie, Volume 58, Issue 3, Pages 214-219 for a recent review.